# How do I make an 'a' tag with a mailto href and bindAttr to a property?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a model, with a property 'contact_email'. I'd like to make a link with a mailto: href.

I've tried doing the slightly obvious `<a {{bindAttr href="contact_email"}}>Email</a>` but of course this is does not have the mailto: bit.

How can I combine mailto: with the property contact_email?

Comment: I could do the inelegant thing and just have a property called mailto_contact_email that concats mailto: with `this.get('contact_email')`. Seems like handlebars must have a way of distinguishing and I just can't find it.

Comment: If you directly load the emailaddress from a model and using the older Handlebars in you app you __can__ use `<a href="mailto:{{unboud emailaddress}}">Send email</a>` in your view. However if you need dynamically binding/updating within the view, look at the new HTMLBars features which support this too with the same syntax as I provided.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the moment, the only workable approach is to use a computed property (as you described in your comment).

One thing that might make this more tolerable, if you find yourself doing this often, is to create a computed property "macro":

```
App.computed.mailto = function(property) {
  return function() {
    return "mailto:" + this.get(property);
  }.property(property);
};
```

Then you could do this in your controller:

```
var mailto = App.computed.mailto;

App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  mailtoContactEmail: mailto('contactEmail')
});
```

Comment: How about using a Handlebar Helper for it ?

Comment: You can't put handlebars helpers inside of the values in bindAttr, so that won't work.

Comment: I have written a handlebar helper. Current I am not able to handle binding of value inside helpers. Is there any good way to do that ? Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/devilankur18/YgLRb/2/

Comment: @AnkurAgarwal Handlebars helpers that emit bound attributes are not currently supported. What you are trying to do isn't going to work.

Comment: I don't doubt that the computed property will work, but I don't think a controller should be responsible for something like this. A mailto link is pure representation. This kind of logic should be processed in the view.

Comment: Is this still the case one year later? Just getting going with Ember myself and this is what I wound up doing, but I agree with s.meijer.

Answer (score 5):

Register a simple bounded Ember Handlebars helper  (`Em.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper`)

```
Em.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('mailTo', function (emailAddress, label) {
    emailAddress = Em.Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(emailAddress);
    label = (arguments.length == 2) ? emailAddress : Em.Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(label);

    var link = '<a href="mailto:' + emailAddress + '">' + label + '</a>';
    return new Em.Handlebars.SafeString(link);
});
```

And use it like this:

```
simple mailto link:
{{mailTo emailAddress}} 
(output: <a href="mailto:foobar@example.com">foobar@example.com</a>)

mailto link with alternate label
{{mailTo emailAddress username}}
(output: <a href="mailto:foobar@example.com">foobar</a>)
```

Model used:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr('string'),
    emailAddress: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Both values (the email address as well as the optional alternate label) are bounded to the model, and will change whenever the model changes.

Created a JSFiddle to demonstrate the changing model: http://jsfiddle.net/We6B9/

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of [ember cli](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/), you could do it like this:

In your view:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
    layoutName: 'layouts/legal',
    templateName: 'views/legal/tou',
    tagName: 'main',
    classNames: 'view-legal-wrapper',
    varViewTitle: 'Terms and Conditions',
    varCompanySupportEmail: 'test@gmail.com'
});
```

In your handlebars template:

```
<a href="mailto:{{unbound view.varCompanySupportEmail}}?subject=Support%20Request">{{view.varCompanySupportEmail}}</a>
```

Current setup at the time of this post:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1 
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.b45e23ba 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.1 
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a Handlebar Helper can be generic solution to the problem for all such use cases

Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/devilankur18/YgLRb/1/

```
  var getBindingValue = function(context, options, path) {

  var normalized = Ember.Handlebars.normalizePath(null, path, options.data),
      thisContext;

  if (normalized.isKeyword) {
    thisContext = normalized.root;
  } else if (!Ember.isGlobalPath(path)) {
    thisContext = context;
  } else {
    thisContext = null;
  }

  return Em.Handlebars.get(thisContext, normalized.path);

};

Handlebars.registerHelper('mail_to', function(context, options) {
      var value = getBindingValue(this, options, context);

          return 'href=mailto:' + value 

});

var App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({ email: "test@somthing.com" });


App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/'
    })
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to do this using emblem as follows:

```
a href="mailto:{{unbound email}}" Email
```

Which means you should be able to do something like:

```
<a href="mailto:{{unbound email}}">Email</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `concat` helper:

`<a href={{concat "mailto:" model.emailAddress}}>{{model.emailAddress}}</a>`